# htaccess - redirect to ignore nested subdirectory and if possible make entire site non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root, subdirectory

I have an issue that's too complex for me to handle, but I'm betting someone has had to do this before, so please let me hear from you.  ;)

**Here's the situation:**

I've got 1 main domain with 3 subdirectories that are nested within each other

(from top to bottom)
`http://main-domain.com`
then
`http://main-domain.com/company-name/`
then
`http://main-domain.com/company-name/blog/`

There's currently 3 .htaccess files -- 1 in each of the 3 directories shown above.

**What's the problem?**

Instead of having www.main-domain.com/company-name/blog/whatever, I'd like to have main-domain.com/blog/whatever

So, I want to drop the www AND more importantly, drop the middle subdirectory; i.e. /company-name/

I hope that the following examples will help to illustrate the point.

`http://main-domain.com/company-name/index.php` should be changed to `http://main-domain.com/index.php`

`http://main-domain.com/company-name/blog/my-first-article/` should be changed to `http://main-domain.com/blog/my-first-article/`

**Why do I need this?**

I need a shorter URL that is more SEO-friendly.  I have too many backlinks that use the 'old' urls, so I need to mod-rewrite them all.

**Here are My Current 3 htaccess files**

**root htaccess: main-domain.com**

```
#Bypass InoCore Templating System

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /reservations/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /reservations/default.php [L]

Options -Indexes

</IfModule>

#END Bypass

#301 REDIRECT

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^info.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain3.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^main-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.main-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

**company-name htaccess: main-domain.com/company-name/**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^maping.php /maping.php

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]

#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

#BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /company-name/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /company-name/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

**blog htaccess: main-domain.com/company-name/blog/**

```
RewriteEngine off

#BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /company-name/blog/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /company-name/blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

---

Answer (score 1):

### Your correct and compact root .htaccess should be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^info.php - [L]

# match all the domains in single condition while www. is optional
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3|main-domain)\.(com|tld)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^company-name/(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

- R=301 will redirect with https status 301
- L will make last rule
- NE is for no escaping query string
- NC is for ignore case comparison
- $1 is your REQUEST_URI matching group

Comment: Hi & thanks for leaving my something to try!  I've got 1 concern before I try it and that's *how* will that code *know* to redirect *only* to the /blog/ folder when there are more folders in the root (and elsewhere) than just that one group of nested folders?

Comment: Sorry -- had to break up the comment -- too long.  :)

Maybe I'm seeing it wrong and more than likely I didn't explain the situation fully, and based on what little I know, it looks like ^[\/]+/(.*)$ is going to tell it to 'jump' any request for a directory (with at least 1 character) to the root -- and that's probably a great solution if I only had, like I say, just 1 group of nested directories, but there's /images/, /reservations/, etc.  Won't those get **fixed** too?  Thanks!

Comment: Changed my answer to ONLY redirect `*/blog/*` type of URLs thus keeping others like /images/, /reservations/ etc untouched. I also edited your question to make it more readable. You need to use code tag (`{}` button) to show your code like above.

Comment: Oh very nice formatting -- I wasn't aware of the code tag; just that it wasn't working the way I put it in there.  ;)  So to be clear, I type {http://domain.com} and it'll format it correctly?  Nope, but I found it below in the 'Comment' section.  On my end it says to use the ` symbol, not the {, but anyways, I got it to work.  :)

Comment: I guess I'm not doing it right.  "You need to use code tag ({} button) to show your code" -- which one is that?  Let's try `http://domain1.com`

Comment: Yes and you enclose them in reverse ticks **`** like this as well like: `domain.com` to escape it from being treated as URL. btw did my answer work for you in anyway?

Comment: Now that I've got that down pat, let me try your code in my htaccess file.  I take it it goes in my root htccess and not in any of my other directories?

Comment: I'll have to wait until Friday/Saturday EST until I can mess with the system again.  I caused too much interference the last time, that I've been 'banned' until a lower server dip.  Thanks for answering!  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: While I have some time before I can implement this, I was thinking that maybe this isn't what I want to do (or at least the correct directory).  I think we've addressed part of the problem, but there's still the issue with redirecting say, `http://widgets-inc.com/company-name/hi-there.html` to `http://widgets-inc.com/hi-there.html`

I want to 'drop' the /company-name/ text from **all** URLs, so how do you do that too?

Comment: Furthermore, did you happen to see this in my root htaccess file?  


`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tld [NC]RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]`


If I use your solution, `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.widgets-inc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[\/]+/(blog/.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]` and change the 'blog' to 'company-name', won't this create a 'loop' conflict with those 2 rewrite rules?

Comment: Actually there is already an infinite redirection in your .htaccess at the last rule: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]` which is **effectively** this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /company-name/$1 [R=301,NC]` Moreover your root .htaccess has many redundant lines that can be minimized into a much simpler one.

Comment: I have tried to fix your root's .htaccess file, please see my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I haven't tried it yet -- still waiting until tonight to modify the files.  I think I know what's going on, but if you could walk me thru it, I'd appreciate it a lot. 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/company-name/$1 [R=301,L]`  


So it's looking for any match of the 3 'add-on' domains and forwarding it to the 'main' domain along with the /company-name/ directory.

Does this also cover the non-www request?  Is that what this piece of code does?

`^(www\.)?`

Comment: Yes it does cover non-www domains also. `^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.com` means text in parenthesis `www.` is optional. And then it will accept domain1 OR domain2 OR domain3 followed by `.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  Got 1 more question.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/company-name/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /company-name/$1 [R=301,L]`

...then takes the 'main' domain and if it's asked for the /company-name/ directory (and only that directory), it send you to root/company-name/whatever-the-request-was

I wonder, should the /company-name/ actually be taken out so that it goes to the root?  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Thanks.

Comment: Thinking long-term, what happens when someone links to my old page at say http://main-domain.com/company-name/blog/my-article using the 'new' redirect as http://main-domain.com/blog/my-old-article that shows up in the title bar?  Will my page still be 'found'?

Comment: Actually `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` rule means `infinite loop` effectively. Since `/foo` will remain `/foo` and `/` will remain `/`. I didn't understand intent behind these lines in bottom of your .htaccess file so commented it with `suspicious rule` and removed infinite looping by adding `%{THE_REQUEST} !/company-name/ [NC]` which says if request does NOT have `/company-name/` then redirect. But this rules does need one serious look.

Comment: If I wanted to take all www and non-www requests and make it direct to a non-www main-domain, would the code look like this?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/company-name/$1 [R=301,L]

# suspicious rule - fixed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/company-name/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /company-name/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I will sincerely advise to spell out the proper requirement in your question above. Since the first time the question was posted, nature of problem has changed a lot and it is really very confusing to look at multiple .htaccess files you posted, not really clear what the real intent is. Rewrite rules can be a slippery rope if not thought out properly.

Comment: The intent for the last 2 rewrite conditions were to take both the www and non-www request and forward it to the /company-name/ directory and essentially 'skipping' the root.  All of our files are working on a folder called 'compaany-name', so besides the htaccess file and ftpquote files, there's nothing else in the root and moving all the website files to root isn't possible due to coding hooks everywhere, that's why I wanted to 'remove' the /company-name/ directory to the viewer, but leave it on the server.  Does that make sense, or am I doing that wrong?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I'm trying the best that I can.  What do you propose?

Comment: 1 htaccess file is in each subdirectory: root, company-name, and blog.  I included those in case all 3 had to talk to each other.

Comment: I think I need to understand your directory structure first. Is it like this: `*/public_html`, `*/public_html/company-name/` and then `*/public_html/company-name/blog` or `*/public_html/blog/` I means is blog a sub-directory under company-name or blog is at same level as company-name under root?

Comment: Or could it be that all the subdirectories: root, company-name, and blog are at same level in file system?

Comment: nested - meaning under each other.  blog is a sub-directory of company-name which is a sub-directory of root.  I rewrote the question, with examples, so maybe this will help.

Comment: not on same level. blog is under company-name.  company-name is under root (public_html).

Comment: yes thanks for updating question and answering my question. It definitely helped me understand your environment better.

Comment: Thanks for hanging with me.  I wouldn't know what else to do.  I've screwed up the server so many times 'trying' to find the solution, that I've about given up.

Comment: So as per your latest comments and rephrased question I have updated my answer as well which I believe would work fine. But at the same time there is this series of nested .htaccess files that may impact normal functioning of these rules. I have updated your root's .htaccess as well so let me know how it goes in your final testing.

Comment: Thanks for your recent update.  I think, if I follow this correctly, that "if request does NOT have /company-name/ then redirect."  I think I need it to go the other way, or "if request DOES have /company-name/ then redirect to a url without."  Does that make sense? From the request above, `http://main-domain.com/company-name/index.php` should be changed to `http://main-domain.com/index.php`

Comment: I don't want /company-name/ to be present on **any** URL **after** the redirect/rewrite.

Comment: You can enter in a url with /company-name/ in the URL bar, but it has to be returned without that directory.

Comment: I don't know how else to say it.  ;)

Comment: You wrote in above comments `The intent for the last 2 rewrite conditions were to take both the www and non-www request and forward it to the /company-name/ directory and essentially 'skipping' the root` and now you wrote `I don't want /company-name/ to be present on any URL after the redirect/rewrite` those are 2 contradicting statement and causing confusion at least to me.

Comment: And pls note that my answer `RewriteRule ^company-name/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]` is already redirecting `/company-name/whatever` to `/whatever`. Apart from this it is the last rule in your root .htaccess file that I'm not too sure about. May be you need to just replace that last rule with my answer and it will work out for you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the above comments that you read went I posted what those 2 rewrites were for; however, that was an explanation as to why they are in the current htaccess file to begin with and not what I want to have happen.  There's a difference -- what the htaccess file says now (which is not what I want, but works) vs. this new version (which is trying to do what I need it too).  I apologize for making you create a condition that isn't what I want.  I was trying to explain what the current condition is, not what I'd like to have happen.

Comment: In part of the request at the very top, "So, I want to drop the www AND more importantly, drop the middle subdirectory; i.e. /company-name/".  Again, I am sorry to confuse you.

Comment: I apologize again, I've been looking at the larger gray area under your answer and not the smaller version. So I couldn't see where you were making updates.  Typo note, it should be a NC instead of "NE is for ignore case comparison" and could you update the "Your correct and compact root .htaccess should be like this:" answer to include the other portion so that I know where to insert it in the htaccess file?  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I removed little segment from my answer and changes directly into root .htaccess. Please see my proposed .htaccess file under `"Your correct and compact root .htaccess should be like this:"` heading.

Comment: Well, the code didn't work. If I click on a link that is supposed to go to main-domain.com/company-name/insurance, it does NOT redirect to main-domain.com/insurance -- it just gives me the same url that I asked for.

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that not all 'old domains' (domain1, domain2, domain3) have the same file structure as the 'new' main-domain; i.e. they may not have /company-name/ as a sub-directory.  So when I type in domain1.com/blog it gives me an 404 error and not a redirect.  It redirects IF I only type in "domain1.com".  I would think that I would want domain1.com/anything to be redirected to my 'new' home page which is "main-domain.com"

Comment: I'm also confused with your code as there are 2 variables that I am not sure if they are the same thing, or something different.  `^(www.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3|main-domain)\.(com|tld)$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^company-name/(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]`  Is "main-domain" in the first condition = "domain.tld" in the second, or something completely different?  "main-domain.com" is my working domain.

Comment: Regardless, I've tried both and it still doesn't work.  Another issue:  if I type in "main-domain.com", by itself, it's going to be matched to see if there's a /company-name/ sub-directory, but what it there isn't one?  What happens?  That's great for the example where I have "main-domain.com/reservations/", so as that is not messed with, but I'll need "main-domain.com/index.php" to get redirected to "main-domain.com/company-name/index.php, yet SHOW "main-domain.com/index.php" in the url bar.

Comment: So I think we're talking about 2 conditions, or steps.  1) take all the 'old' domains, no matter what is asked for, and redirect them to "main-domain.com/company-name/" -- which is my working index page.  2) next, take all the "main-domain.com/company-name/whatevers" and shorten it.

Comment: You seem to have a hell of a setup at your end, 4-5 different domains and not all have same directory structure :) Do they all have same DOCUMENT_ROOT or not? I would suggest having a separate rule for each DOCUMENT_ROOT (or directory structure). It is difficult for me to provide you answer without full visibility into your setup. It would have been better if you have provided all the information in your question like `domain1: directory structure1 and you expected behavior for the domain1` then `domain2: directory structure2 and you expected behavior for the domain2` etc.

Comment: I agree -- that is if I knew.  I think all the 'old' domains are just domain redirects, but I also don't know how many backlinks are associated with each domain and that's why I'd like to redirect them.  These 'old' domains aren't the main issue, but the fact that nothing seems to be redirecting is.  Does a portion of your code need to go inside one /company-name/ sub-directory to work?

Comment: Just for testing I would suggest first you comment out my `RewriteCond ` above and then see if redirection happens or not. My rule needs to be in your root .htaccess file.

Comment: I did & it didn't work either.  I'm going to set-up another domain and replicate the file structure and mess with it that way so I can work on it anytime.  When I get it set-up, I'll pass you the info so you can take a look at it too.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: That is fine and just for your testing you can install XAMPP or MAPPP type of packages on your local sandbox. That way you can run your tests as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what XAMPP or MAPPP is, or where to get it, nor if I know how to use it.  :)  I'm not doing a local install (because I don't know how to), so I'm going to use a domain on mine that's not being used for the moment & create the environment there, or at least something like it to see if I can get it to redirect at all.

Comment: XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html for Windows and MAMP: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html for Mac.